# JPA\Hibernate: Persisted list of entities in Singleton

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, design-patterns, singleton

I have a singleton that manages a list of some entities in my DB.

```
public class SchedulledQueue {
    List<MyEntity> entities;
}
```

I need to store this list in my database. So I want a single table that only contains entities from which my singleton could grab all data.

```
TABLE schedulled_queue 
(
  entity_id character varying(32),

  CONSTRAINT schedulled_queue FOREIGN KEY (entity_id)
      REFERENCES tbl_my_entity (entity_id) MATCH SIMPLE
)
```

Is there any way to map my singleton SchedulledQueue in Hibernate to achieve this? Or should I not bother with such thing?

Comment: You should really fix the spelling of `SchedulledQueue`.  Typos in identifiers make life difficult for your colleagues, anyone who's trying to grep through source, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I don't found another way, except to create another Entity and use it through DAO.

```
public class SchedulledQueue {
    List<SchedulledQueueEntity> entities;
}

SchedulledQueueEntity {
    MyEntity ent;
}
```

Also it provided ability to use some additional fields for entity in queue, that we needed some time later.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple SchedulledQueue objects then it makes sense to have one to many relation between SchedulledQueue and MyEntity.

Since your SchedulledQueue in singleton. I don't see any advantage of creating an entity of it.

Comment: What you can do is to have a method in your  DAO layer to get list of MyEntities.  And in your service layer have assign it your singleton

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that. But I don't know any way to store entities into the other table and get it from it (pure SQL is forbidden). And of course I could extend class but, this is not suit for me.